# How can orbitals of Hydrogen and Chlorine atom combine to form molecular orbitals of Hydrogen Chloride?

Tags: bond, molecular-orbital-theory, hybridization

Linear combination of atomic orbitals (LCAO) states that orbitals can only combine if the energies and shape of the orbitals are same. $3p$ orbital of Chlorine and $1s$ orbital of Hydrogen are the ones forming the bond by sharing electrons but how?

Comment: *"Linear combination of atomic orbitals (LCAO) states that orbitals can only combine if the energies and shape of the orbitals are same."* - Who said that? Is there a (reputable) source for this claim?

Comment: Heard it from my chemistry teacher and even some articles online. But after adequate research got to know that this is not correct. The actual conditions for orbitals of atoms to combine is having the same or nearly the same energy and having the same symmetry about the molecular axis. it indeed is possible for  s and p orbitals to combine but a Py orbital wont combine with a Pz orbital due to different symmetries. Got my doubt cleared thanks!

Comment: Yep, that's a better criterion, I agree.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a confusion in this demand.

The atomic orbitals may combine if they have the same energy and if they belong to the same atom. This is the way hybrid orbitals are introduced. But this is not valid for atomic orbitals belonging to different atoms. The $1s$ orbital of hydrogen can combine with a $3p$ orbital from chlorine, or with a $4p$ orbital from bromine, to make a sigma bond, even though their energies are different.